# How to apply horizontal alignment in amchrts legend?

Tags: javascript, legend, amcharts

I'm using amcharts to create my chart, legend is in separate container.

Applying option

```
chart.legend.align = 'right'
```

has no effect

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WmaQZe?=true)

Comment: Can you attach an image of what are you trying to achieve? Column of legend items at the left of the chart?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're looking to align the contents of the legend, i.e. the legend items to the right, and not the entire legend itself (I am presuming this, because the legend is in an external, custom `<div>`, and this is taken straight out of our guides on the subject. If you meant something else please do let us know.), then you'll have to change its `layout`, then align its *contents* to the right via `contentAlign`. E.g.

```js
// Align legend items to the right
chart.legend.layout = "vertical";
chart.legend.contentAlign = "right";
```

Here's a demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/0aa8b7741a25a86fafa48b747077b8e3

I highly recommend checking out our guide, ["Working with Containers"](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/svg-engine/containers/), it contains various details regarding laying things out in amCharts v4. Also, once you align everything to the right, the legend is still going to be locked into the height of its html wrapper, i.e. `150px` in your case, with no way to access the rest of the content. The demo above is a fork of what's found in our ["Making the external legend scrollable" guide](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/chart-legend-in-an-external-container/#Making_legend_scrollable).

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what i'm looking for, much thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[`legend.align`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/legend/#align_property) has no effect, because the width of the legend is `100%`.

> This is used by parent Container when layouting its children.

You should align the content with [`legend.contentAlign`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/legend/#contentAlign_property):

```
chart.legend.contentAlign = 'right';
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxPmyP) I forked your code pen to show the result.

Another error in you code pen is the value of [`legend.valign`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/legend/#valign_property)

Valid values are:

> "top" | "middle" | "bottom" | "none"

See [VerticalAlign](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/verticalalign/).

So you should set it this way:

```
chart.legend.valign = 'middle';
```